# Print a string from ArrayList of String[]?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, dereference

I have an ArrayList full of strings arrays that I built like this:

```
String[] words = new String[tokens.length];
```

I have three arrays like above in my ArrayList:

```
surroundingWords.add(words);
surroundingWords.add(words1);
surroundingWords.add(words2);
```

etc

Now if I want to print out the elements in the String arrays within surroundingWords... I can't.
The closest I can get to displaying the contents of the String[] arrays is their addresses:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@1888759
[Ljava.lang.String;@6e1408
[Ljava.lang.String;@e53108
```

I've tried a lot of different versions of what seems to be the same thing, the last try was:

```
for (int i = 0; i < surroudingWords.size(); i++) {
        String[] strings = surroundingWords.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < strings.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(strings[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I can't get past this because of incompatible types:

```
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String[]
                String[] strings = surroundingWords.get(i);
                                                       ^
```

Help!

I've already tried the solutions here: [Print and access List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983577/java-print-and-access-list-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the `Object` into a `String[]`:

`String[] strings = (String[]) surroundingWords.get(i);`

or use a parameterized ArrayList:

`ArrayList<String[]> surroundingWords = new ArrayList<String[]>();`

Then you won't have to cast the return value from `get()`.

Comment: The ArrayList<String[]> is the current "correct" way of doing it.

Comment: @Kurtis: Unless you're stuck in Pre-1.5 land

Comment: @Poindexter True, that's why I said **current** correct way :)

Answer (score 10):

Try something like this

```
public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String[]> lst = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        lst.add(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"});
        lst.add(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"});
        lst.add(new String[] {"#", "@", "!"});

        for (String[] arr : lst) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1, this is the simplest an most "Java way" to go. The person asking the question should try and learn the behaviour of such java fundamentals as Object.toString() and Arrays / Collections helper classes