# How to print list of arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I have several arrays, I add them to a list of arrays, and then I want to print this list. How can I do this?

```
List<String[]> kList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
kList.add(anArray);
kList.add(anArray2);
System.out.println(kList);//how to print it?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print and access List <String\[\]>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983577/print-and-access-list-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8+ you can use :

```
kList.forEach(array -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)));
```

Before Java 8 :

```
for(String[] array : kList) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(kList.toArray()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do let me know if this answers:
String [] array1= {"P","Q"};
    String [] array2= {"R","S"};

```
List<String[]>listStrArr=new ArrayList<>();
listStrArr.add(array1);
listStrArr.add(array2);

for(String[] arrayElement:listStrArr) {
    for(String str:arrayElement) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8+ streams way:

```
kList.stream()
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

To print all you either have to iterate through the List and print each array with Arrays.toString() with a loop .

**Exmple :**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class  printListOfArrays{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                 List<String[]> kList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                                 String [] anArray= {"Stack"}; 
                                 String [] anArray2= {"Overflow"};
                                  kList.add(anArray);
                                  kList.add(anArray2);
                                  for (String[] strings : kList) {
                                  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings)); 
                                    }
    }


}
```

Output :

```
[Stack]
[Overflow]
```