# Java - print contents of a queue

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, queue

I have a queue (where each element is an array of integer) defined as -

`Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>();`

When I try to print the queue, I get  output like this as it prints the array object -

`[[I@58d25a40]`

How can I override the `toString()` method of Queue class to get the correct output ? I donot want to get the output by iterating over the queue. I hope to achieve it somehow by overriding the `toString()` method.

Comment: When we create any custom class, we can define the toString() method within that class how to print that object once that object is placed within a System.out.print() statement. Is  there any similar way to achieve this with Queue class ?

Comment: No, and `Queue` is not a class, it's an interface. The concrete class you're using is `LinkedList`. What you *could* do is a custom class that implements `Queue`, maybe backed by a `LinkedList`, and that class can have a custom `toString` method.

Comment: By the way, I've reopened your question, but [here's a more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947403/how-to-print-list-of-arrays-in-java) about printing lists of arrays.

Comment: *"I donot want to get the output by iterating over the queue. I hope to achieve it somehow by overriding the `toString()` method."* You'll have to iterate eventually, one way or another. You can just *hide* that iteration in another method, but the iteration will still be there under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>() {
  @Override public String toString() {
    return "[" +
      stream()
      .map(Arrays::toString)
      .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) +
      "]";
  }
};

queue.add(new int[] {1, 2});
queue.add(new int[] {3, 4});
System.out.println(queue);
```

printing:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Which is presumably what you want.

This isn't necessarily a good idea. `toString()` should be used solely for debugging purposes: toString demands nothing of implementations, not even that they are consistent. Most things I can think of that would lead one to ask this question are problematic.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I override the `toString()` method of `Queue` class to get the correct output ?

You can't.

For starters, `Queue` is not a class, it's an interface. The concrete class you're using is `LinkedList`.

More concretely what you could do is defining a custom class that implements `Queue` and extends, for example `LinkedList`, and that class can have a custom `toString` method (see implementation below).

> I donot want to get the output by iterating over the queue. I hope to achieve it somehow by overriding the `toString()` method.

You'll have to iterate eventually, one way or another. You can just hide that iteration in another method, but the iteration will still be there under the hood.

Here's a quick blueprint of what you can do

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ArrayQueue extends LinkedList<int[]> implements Queue<int[]> {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.stream()
            .map(Arrays::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
    }
}
```

And a test program

```
import java.util.Queue;

public class ArrayQueueTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Queue<int[]> q = new ArrayQueue();
        q.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
        q.add(new int[]{4, 5, 6});
        q.add(new int[]{7, 8, 9});
        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

Running this yields

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```